# reuse jqplot object to load or replot data

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I am using JqPlot for charts , my problem is i want to load different data on different click events.

But once the chart is created and loaded with the data for the first time; i don't know then how to load data when another event fires that means i want to reuse the chart object and want to load/replot the data when events get fired something like...

```
chartObj.data = [graphData]
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how to use plotting in case of me having a pie chart?
grilix's answer does not seem to work for me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That seems to work to replot data.

```
chartObj.series[0].data = [[0, 4], [1, 7], [2, 3]];
chartObj.replot();
```

Also, you can check this: https://groups.google.com/group/jqplot-users/browse_thread/thread/59df82899617242b/77fe0972f88aef6d%3Fq%3D%2522Groups.%2BCom%2522%2377fe0972f88aef6d&ei=iGwTS6eaOpW8Qpmqic0O&sa=t&ct=res&cd=71&source=groups&usg=AFQjCNHotAa6Z5CIi_-BGTHr_k766ZXXLQ?hl=en, hope it helps.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19471949 - great answer with test :) Faster is to destroy plot and reinitilize it with new data.

Comment: According to the documentation, Data should NOT be specified in the options object. http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#jqPlot.data. It does not always work as shown by http://jsfiddle.net/ZqCXP/602/ compared to http://jsfiddle.net/ZqCXP/601/ or http://jsfiddle.net/ZqCXP/600/

Answer (score 18):

Though this is an old question.

As the accepted Answer didn't work for me and i couldn't find a solution in the jqPlot docs either. I came to this solution

```
var series = [[1,2],[2,3]];
chartObj.replot({data:series});
```

Src: Taking a look at the `replot` function.

```
function (am) {
    var an = am || {};
    var ap = an.data || null;
    var al = (an.clear === false) ? false : true;
    var ao = an.resetAxes || false;
    delete an.data;
    delete an.clear;
    delete an.resetAxes;
    this.target.trigger("jqplotPreReplot");
    if (al) {
        this.destroy()
    }
    if (ap || !L.isEmptyObject(an)) {
        this.reInitialize(ap, an)
    } else {
        this.quickInit()
    } if (ao) {
        this.resetAxesScale(ao, an.axes)
    }
    this.draw();
    this.target.trigger("jqplotPostReplot")
}
```

The line 
`if (ap || !L.isEmptyObject(an)) {
            this.reInitialize(ap, an)
        }`
shows us it needs a truthy value for ap to pass it as first parameter to the internal reinitialize function. which is defined as `var ap = an.data || null;`

Its as simple as this but unfortunately not documented anywhere i could find it

---

Note that if you want to redraw some things defined in your jqPlot options, like legend labels, you can just pass any option to the replot function. Just remember the actual series to replot has to be named "data"

```
var options = {
     series : [{
            label: 'Replotted Series',
            linePattern: 'dashed'
     }],
   //^^^ The options for the plot
     data : [[1,2],[2,3]]
   //^^^ The actual series which should get reploted
}
chartObj.replot (options)
```

Comment: THANK YOU for this.  been looking all morning for how to pass in this data.  Only thing that worked on the net.

Comment: You're welcome =)
Yeah, thats exactly what forced me to take a look at the source..

Comment: According to the documentation, Data should NOT be specified in the options object. jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#jqPlot.data

Comment: @PaulH Thank you! do you currently have any jqPlot project you're working on and could verify passing the data as second argument works for replotting the data? I'd update the answer accordingly.

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 the .replot() method works, but should not be used. That is why I use the $.jqplot() method which is about as fast http://jsfiddle.net/ZqCXP/600/

Answer (score 2):

jqplot allows for a fast dynamic data update.

According to the [documentation](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#jqPlot.data) (data section), *"Data should NOT be specified in the options object ..."* ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZqCXP/601/))

```
plot1.replot({data: [storedData]}); // data should not be passed this way
```

*"... but be passed in as the second argument to the $.jqplot() function."*

```
if (plot1) plot1.destroy();
plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [storedData]); // similar speed to replot
```

The [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZqCXP/600/) shows this can be done with similar performance.

Answer (score 1):

Empty graph div, before rendering the graph

```
$('#graphDiv').empty();
plot = $.jqplot('graphDiv', [graphValues], graphOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

[The API has a replot/redraw method](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#jqPlot.replot)

> **Redraw** This enables plot data and properties to be changed and then to
>   comletely clear the plot and redraw.

Comment: well the problem is i don't know how to use it , can you please give me the example ?